# Iterate through the incoming data

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I have Receiving NSData like 210502113c4d  from the server . I am getting this data into NSString format . I want to retrieve the 3 byte from this incoming data i.e. 2105 **02** 113c4d. I have tried following :

```
NSData *demoData=[string dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSLog(@"demo data :%@",demoData);
const char *bytes=[data bytes];
NSMutableString *result = [NSMutableString string];
for (int i = 0; i < [demoData length]; i++)
{
    [result appendFormat:@"%02hhx", (unsigned char)bytes[i]];
}
```

But its not working . Please suggest me some solution to achieve this ?

Comment: @downvoter:downvote ? its ok. But at least leave some comment before down voting .Otherwise it doesn't matter for me

Answer (score 0):

Code obtains value of the third byte of a string, assuming string contains bytes in hex, in hh format:

```
NSString* string = @"210502113c4d";
NSString* thirdByte = [string substringWithRange:NSRangeFromString(@"4,2")];
NSScanner* scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:thirdByte];
NSUInteger value;
[scanner scanHexInt:&value];
NSLog(@"%u", value); // 2
```